# jboss web services to tranfer files

Tags: java, jboss, web-services

I dont have any experience for web services. please give me some suggestion about the task below.
the task is:
users will send a txt file (size should less than 20K ) from a .NET application, I need to write a web services which runs by jboss 5.x to read this file and edit this file and send the file back to .NET UI to display the edited version.

question is that if the txt file is just text string or binary string, are there any restriction of the string length? if it's binary string, can I need to use BinaryReader class to read it? or not need special reader to read it? (this could be a dumn question :P)

what if the .NET application can save the file on either the .NET application server or some shared server location, send a download URL to web serivces, can web services download it and read it? JBoss will be run on Linux sever.

After edit the file, how do I send it back?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to find reliable information about limitations in size, this depends on the libraries you use.
I would rather use an attachment than a single string containing the whole file [Handling attachments in SOAP](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-soapatt/)
For .Net see [Add Attachments to a SOAP Message by Using DIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms824597.aspx)

> After edit the file, how do I send it
>   back?
>
> ```
> Request processFile(File) 
> Response UniqueId
>
> Request getProcessedFile(UniqueId)
> Response Edited File
> ```

Comment: Thank you! your suggestion for attachments to a SOAP msg is very helpful!